# How do I debug a Python program (I am coming from a Ruby on Rails/JavaScript background)?

Tags: python, debugging

I make web applications using Ruby on Rails as my backend. I use React and Flux on the frontend, which is JavaScript. I can fully use the debugging tools I need. I simply add the line of code "debugger" anywhere in my app, so that execution stops there. I use byebug gem in Rails. When the "debugger" line of code is executed on backend code, the debugging happens on the command line; when it happens in JavaScript code, the debugging happens in Chrome Dev Tools. In other words, I can work very quickly to debug.

What is the equivalent convenient debugging tool in Python? In other words, what should a person who can already program in general, and just wants to rapidly be able to debug in Python use? I am using Atom editor (like I use when I am making a web app).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html for a quick guide https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/ may help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `pdb`

To add a breakpoint, insert:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

where you want to stop.

NB:
Since python 3.7, you just can do

```
breakpoint()
```

In the debugger mode you can use the following [commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).